# LaTeX-like cross-referencing in epub?

Tags: latex, epub

Are there any markup languages or compilers that will allow me to use LaTeX like cross-referencing commands (label and ref) and then create an epub document?

Everything I've tried so far (pandoc including) has some shortcomings.

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc v1.9 has just been released and has many improvements, including adding internal and external links to the EPUB writer. Also note that pandoc supports DocBook output, which community has its own independent paths to EPUB via XSLT.

Also check out the "Extras" page in the Pandoc wiki, I've been excited lately by Aditya's "filter" script, not sure if that would be helpful for your use case though.